# C# wrapper class for c++ lib dll

Tags: c#, c++, interop, wrapper, dllimport

I am trying to create a class in c# to access the function in a c++ lib. The function in the c++ dll :
`bool WriteReply(const unsigned char *reply, const unsigned long reply_length)`.

A sample of how its used in c++:-

```
unsigned short msg_id = 0x0000;                      
byte msg_body[] = {(byte)(GetTickCount()/0x100)};    // a random value for loopback data

    // combine the message id and message body into an big msg
    unsigned long msg_length = sizeof(msg_id)+sizeof(msg_body);
    byte* big_msg = new byte[msg_length];
    big_msg[0] = LOBYTE(msg_id);
    big_msg[1] = HIBYTE(msg_id);
    memcpy((void*)&big_msg[2], (void*)msg_body, sizeof(msg_body));

    // send the big message
    if (!big_dev.WriteReply(big_msg, msg_length))
    {
        //do something here
    }
```

I can't seem to pass the function from c# to the dll (`AccessViolationException`). This is the command i've tried:-

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[3] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytearray.Length);
Marshal.Copy(bytearray, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytearray.Length);

bool writestatus = (bool)NativeMethods.WriteReply(unmanagedPointer, (uint)bytearray.Length);
```

and on the import side:-

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll", EntryPoint = "WriteReply")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
internal static extern bool WriteReply(IntPtr msg, uint reply_length);
```

Please let me know where have i gone wrong?Thanks!

Comment: You are close.  Minus the reply_length argument, that's an uint, not an ulong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans Passant, but it doesn't work. I'm still getting the AccessViolationException. Any other suggestions? Why do you say that the reply_length's an uint, not ulong anyways? Thanks!

Comment: Because *long* is 32-bits in C++.  Use a debugger to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370895/how-do-i-pass-from-c-sharp-to-c-dll

Comment: What are the semantics for `WriteReply`? The function signature is not enough. Which way does that data flow? Is `reply` a null-terminated string?

Comment: @Hans: Your statement is true on Windows, but not necessarily elsewhere, there are for instance 64-bit longs on 64-bit Linuxes.

Comment: @Johann - AccessViolationException and ".dll" should be good selectors for the platform.  And having trouble making it work :)

Comment: @David Hefferman, the flow is from c# to c++ lib. a string is supposed to be sent from c# to c++ lib dll and the dll is supposed to return a boolean value. My problem is that I'm unable to pass the arguments from c# to c++ properly :(

Comment: Is the string meant to be a null terminated C string?

Comment: @David Hefferman no, its not. This is what I've done now, but am still getting the same error.                                 'IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytearray.Length);
      Marshal.Copy(bytearray, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytearray.Length);

        writestatus = (bool)NativeMethods.WriteReply(unmanagedPointer, (uint)bytearray.Length);' and on the import side:-                           '[DllImport("dllname.dll", EntryPoint = "WriteReply")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
 internal static extern bool WriteReply(IntPtr msg, uint reply_length);'

Comment: Add the C++ code to the question

Comment: @David Heffernan I don't have the c++ codes, its a 3rd party .dll...but I do have a sample of how its handled in c++ (edited above)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your C++ method uses the string and does not modify it...

Try this

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool __cdecl WriteReply(const unsigned char *reply, const unsigned long reply_length);


[DllImport("libfile.dll", EntryPoint = "WriteReply")]
private static extern bool WriteReplyExternal(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] [Out] string replyString,
    [Out] UInt32 replyLength);
```

Or better yet (since C strings are null-terminated and the buffer is readonly, so you don't have to worry about buffer overflow, the length parameter is redudant):

```
__declspec(dllexport) bool __cdecl WriteReply(const unsigned char *reply);


[DllImport("libfile.dll", EntryPoint = "WriteReply")]
private static extern bool WriteReplyExternal(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] [Out] string replyString);
```

These will work if the method is not within a class, otherwise you will need to [use the C++ mangled name as the entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2443170/38368).

If your string contains characters outside the 1...127 ASCII range (e.g. non-English letters), you should use wchar_t instead of char in the C++ and LPWStr instead of LPStr in the marshalling.

Edit:

You need to wrap the private method with another method with a signature that is more appropriate for .NET e.g.

```
public void WriteReply(string message)
{
    var result = WriteReplyExternal(message, message.Length);
    if (result == false)
        throw new ApplicationException("WriteReplay failed ...");
}
```

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for the reply. Actually the function is where the c# lib is to pass a string containing a msg as well as its length to the c++ lib dll. However the c++ lib dll only accepts these arguments: "const unsigned char *reply" as well as "const unsigned long reply_length". my problem is i don't know how to pass the string and length from c# to c++ dll and accept the boolean reply from the c++ dll. Any suggestions?Thanks!

Comment: Hi, tried that..didn't work too..i think i have ot pass it as a pointer to a byte array, just like how it was handled in the c++ example code (refer above). What do you think?Thanks!

Comment: First of all, char array not byte array, second of all I have done this many times with strings. Open your C++ DLL with depends (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and check the exposed signature.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest addition of code provides a clue as to the real problem:

```
if (!big_dev.WriteReply(big_msg, msg_length))
```

This cannot work because `WriteReply` is an member function. You need to be calling a C style function rather than a C++ member function. The latter requires an instance (`big_dev` in the code sample).

Comment: I've cleaned the codes/question here and the ReplyMsg/WriteReply is actually typo here; I've corrected it here as per how it is in the codes. Am about to try out Danny Varod's suggestion now:)

Comment: The point in my answer stands. If this is a member function then nothing in Danny's answer will help. Even if it was not a member function, Danny's answer would not help. As you have said already, this is not a null-terminated string and so everything in Danny's answer does not apply. Trial and error is not what you need here. You need to think about the problem.

Comment: I dont understand your reply. The c++ sample file works fine. It just doesn't work when I try to access the .dll from c#.

Comment: The C++ code appears to be calling a member function. Is that so?